# web service not working except on local machine

Tags: web-services, wsdl, localhost

I have published a web service into a computer which is connected with mine. The two pc's can ping each other. The web service works perfectly in the local machine as it is called as below:

```
http://localhost:9000/flori/koci?wsdl
```

when it is called from my pc (with ip) as `http://1.1.1.1:9000/flori/koci?wsdl` it doesn't display the methods.

Can you give me a hint on this.

thnx in advance.

Comment: What language, API and hosting environment are you using? (e.g. .NET, WCF, IIS7 or Java, Metro, Apache 2)

Comment: On which server this service is hosted ? Jboss / Tomcat / ?? Did you try the URL in browser ? Any proxy settings in browser set ?

Comment: it is hosted on a local pc which is on the same lan. i have tried the url in different browsers, but it doesn't display anything. there is a proxy on the browser set, but it is the same result when i remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is blocked for `firewall` or you don't permissions through `port` or `ip`. :)

Answer (score -1):

the corresponding IP address for localhost is 127.0.0.1

You can try using http: //127.0.0.1:9000/flori/koci?wsdl on local-machine using IP.
And to get your system dynamic ip run the ipconfig command to get the IPv4 address and use that from other systems on network.